# How to assign some one function to several events?

Tags: javascript, function, events, onload, onscroll

Maybe it is dumb question, but how can I do something like this in JavaScript:

```
document.onload = function() { typeText(); }
window.onscroll = function() { typeText(); }

function typeText() { ... }
```

?

P.S.: Actually, this example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
function typeText() { ... }

document.onload = typeText;
window.onscroll = typeText;
```

If you'd also like to pass in parameters, I'd recommend looking at the `.bind()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

But an example would look like this:

```
document.onload = typeText.bind(this, param1, param2);
```

Comment: Typetext doesn't has to be on top. JavaScript parses the function first. His own example also works

Comment: Totally, agree. More just stylistic

Comment: @Mouser ... should work, but it doesn't. Maybe there is a mistake in body of function, but why does it work on `window.onscroll` then?

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky I attached an alert to the function and got a dozen in IE. Try using the development tools (F12) and see if there's another error on your page.

Comment: @Mouser `window.onscroll = typeText; document.onload = alert("Hi");` works well.